# How do I pass a partial function to a list which contains partial function?

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
def bigger[T <% Ordered[T]](compare: T)(a: ResultSet, columnName: String): Boolean =
  a.getObject(columnName).asInstanceOf[T] > compare

var rules = List[(ResultSet,String) => Boolean]()   

rules += bigger[Int](1000) //doesn't work, compile error

val rule = bigger(1000) _ _ 
rules += rule //still doesn't work, compile error
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use only a single `_` and use `+:=` to add elements to `rules`:

```
rules +:= bigger[Int](1000) _
```

Comment: thanks, but why need only one _? that function took 2 parameters.

Comment: The `_` isn't a placeholder for parameters, instead it tells the compiler to create a closure representing the partially applied function or method. It is completely different from the `_` used when creating anonymous functions.

Comment: One may add that you can use `:+=` if you want to _append_ elements or `+:=` if you want to _prepend_ the element.